# onfocus breaks when user resizes the the textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/0bo4ry64/2/

```
<textarea class='err' style='resize:none;' rows='1' cols='29' placeholder='Enter error message...' onfocus='this.rows=5; this.cols=40;' onblur='this.rows=1; this.cols=29;'"+"name='wiz"+i+"'></textarea>
<textarea class='err' rows='1' cols='29' placeholder='Enter error message...' onfocus='this.rows=5; this.cols=40;' onblur='this.rows=1; this.cols=29;'"+"name='wiz"+i+"'></textarea>
```

Hopefully that fiddle shows what is wrong. OK so my question is, How do I make it so that if the user resizes the textarea, the onblur and onfocus events will still fire and correctly shrink and grow the textarea? In the fiddle you will find two textarea's one with the resize disable to show what the textarea is suppose to do and the other without it disabled. If you click in each box they will grow and click away they will shrink. In the second one, if you resize it, then click away and/or into it won't activate the events.

Comment: The events  still work after resize. Check the html to see the attributes change, even onblur after resize

Answer (score 0):

the `resize` option of textarea changes it CSS and not its rows and cols attributes. so, you should change the height and the width to the default ones onblur.

Using jQuery:

```
$(".err").on('focusin', function() {
    $(this).attr('rows', 5).attr('cols', 40);
});

$(".err").on('focusout', function() {
    $(this).css({'height': '', 'width': ''})
    .attr('rows', 1).attr('cols', 29);
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0bo4ry64/3/)

Comment: OK, this does work, thank you, but i forgot one detail, I have many of this textarea's so using the class name wont work because they all have the same class name, I'm sorry

Comment: It will work. when using `$(this)`, and not the class name selector.

Comment: Not sure why you replaced focus/blur with focusin/focusout, but it works well and it's much better than that inline stuff. You may want to set resize style like I did in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So after playing around there seems to be some internal property to the input object that changes and prevents cols and rows from changing the size afterwards.  So I came up with a solution of replacing itself with a new textarea with the expected values that gets the behavior you are wanting.

`<textarea class='err' rows='1' cols='29' placeholder='Enter error message...' onfocus='this.rows=5; this.cols=40;' onblur='this.rows=1; this.cols=29;var text = document.createElement("textarea"); text.attributes = this.attributes; text.value = this.value; text.onblur = this.onblur; text.onfocus = this.onfocus; this.replaceWith(text)'></textarea>`

Comment: That works, but how would i get it to go to the exact size it was and keep the placeholder? **Never mind** I figured it out, thanks for your help.

Comment: Just copy those attributes over like I did for the event handlers.

Comment: hey if I answered your question could you please vote/select appropriately? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you looks at the html in the browser dev tools, you'll see the events don't break. The issue is that on resize the browser sets some styles like margin, width and height. Just unset them onblur, and also toggle the resize style.

```
<textarea class='err' style='resize:none;' rows='1' cols='29' placeholder='Enter error message...' onfocus='this.rows=5; this.cols=40;this.style.resize="both"' onblur='this.rows=1; this.cols=29;this.style.width="";this.style.height="";this.style.margin="";this.style.resize="none"'></textarea>
```

I also tried with this.style object, but for some reason that doesn't replace the resize style onblur, making the blurred textarea resizable. Tested in Chrome.

https://jsfiddle.net/0bo4ry64/4/

EDIT: I'm using the inline code because you seem to prefer it, but it's much cleaner and better to do it the way Itay proposed. That one codeblock could handle 100 textareas if you wanted to...